# How to configure jquery datatable to not use statesave while create/initializing dataTable on reload/refresh page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `bStateSave` property in server-side datatable but it always show old state even i reload/refresh page. I want to use `bStateSave` while `_fnAjaxUpdate()` or `fnReloadAjax()` only, not while create/initializing dataTable on reload/refresh page.

Please let me know a way to do this.